# Reshape data frame using a column's unique values as new columns and with missing data

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2

I would like to reshape my old data.frame `data` from long to wide using two variables as the columns for the new data.frame `new.data`. Specifically, I want to take the two variables `data$assessment` and `data$question_id`:

1) Figure out how many `data$question_id` are in each `data$assessment`, so that

2) Each `data$question_id` represents a column in the new data.frame, and

3) Relabel each `data$question_id` to indicate the assessment it belongs to (i.e. Assessment1 and Q1 is Assessment1_Q1, Assessment1 and Q3 is Assessment1_Q3).

However, there are two things to consider:

1) The assessments have different numbers of questions

2) Not all questions were filled out by the participant (i.e. missing data)

Here's the general structure of the old data.frame:

```
> dim(data)
[1] 42106     4
> colnames(data)
[1] "subjectid"      "assessment"     "question_id"    "question_value"
> lapply(data, class)
$subjectid
[1] "integer"

$assessment
[1] "factor"

$question_id
[1] "factor"

$question_value
[1] "factor"
> length(unique(data$subjectid))
[1] 96
> table(data$assessment)

 Assessment1              Assessment2 
        1362                     2102 
 Assessment3              Assessment4 
         966                      864 
 Assessment5              Assessment6 
        1183                     2093 
 Assessment7              Assessment8 
         181                    14208 
 Assessment9             Assessment10
        6734                     2044 
Assessment11             Assessment12
        3129                     2185 
Assessment13             Assessment14
        3962                     1093 
> length(unique(data$question_id))
[1] 431
```

I want my new data.frame `new.data` to have rows representing participants (N=96), columns representing the assessment and question (i.e. Assessment1_Q1), and `new.data$question_value` representing each participant's score on a specific assessment/question. Using `dim(new.data)` should yield  `96    432`

It should look something like this

```
subjectid  Assessment1_Q1  Assessment1_Q2  Assessment1_Q3  Assessment1_Q4    Assessment2_Q1  Assessment2_Q2  Assessment2_Q3  Assessment3_Q1  Assessment3_Q2  Assessment3_Q3  Assessment4_Q1  Assessment4_Q2
        1                               6               7                               5               4               1               2               4               8               6               
        2               5                                               9                               3               1               2               4               8               2               3
        3               3               9               5               4               5               9               2                               3               7               5               5
```

As you can see, the new data.frame's rows are participants, the columns are Assessments/Questions, and the values are the participants' responses (missing responses are left blank.

Comment: Can you show few lines of original dataset so that we can test it with some codes.

Comment: @akrun is `head(data)` okay?

Comment: See [here on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: You can use `dput(droplevels(head(data)))` assuming that you have only 4 columns.

Comment: Try `library(reshape2); dcast(data, subjectid~assessment+question_id, value.var='question_value')`

Comment: Can you check whether the `dcast` code works?

Comment: @akrun It almost worked. The values are all 1 for some reason. I think it's because `class(data$question_value)` is a factor.

Comment: @user2105555  Try converting to `character` and then to numeric (if needed) ie. `data$question_value <- as.numeric(as.character(data$question_value))`  Also you can use the fun.aggregate in `dcast` to get the `mean` or `length` etc..

Comment: @akrun Didn't work. I even tried `as.numeric()` instead of `as.character()`

Comment: Can you update with few lines of your dataset using `dput` so that I can test it ? along with the expected output for that input

Comment: @akrun Is there is way to convert some values into `as.numeric()` and others into `as.numeric()`? I found that some variables were coded as letters (i.e. gender --> M).

Comment: A column can have only a single class. If there is any character value, it willl get converted to `character` or `factor` (depending upon the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or TRUE

Comment: @akrun I updated the `dput` for the first dataset. What sort of expected output do you want?

Comment: Based on that dataset, what do you expect as output?  In the 'assessment' column you have a long string, so I am confused.

Comment: @akrun I just updated the original post. For some reason, the new dataset only has 1 as values, not the original numerical values from the original dataset.